# Running WSF-CPP samples

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to run the Echo sample that comes with WSO2 WSF-CPP, and I get the following errors:

> [Tue Dec 18 14:26:51 2012] [error] dep_engine.c(1008) Axis2
>   Configuration file name not found [Tue Dec 18 14:26:51 2012] [error]
>   dep_engine.c(872) axis2.xml is not available in client repo .  [Tue
>   Dec 18 14:26:51 2012] [error] conf_init.c(201) Loading deployment
>   engine failed for client repository . [Tue Dec 18 14:26:51 2012]
>   [critical] ServiceClient.cpp(223) Cannot create service client

I follow the installation steps in [1](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/dummys-guide-writing-web-service-clients-wso2-wsf-c#Running_Your_First_Web_Service_Client_with_WSO2_WSF_CPP) and I don't have any problem, but I'm thinking that there is something missed.

Thanks in advance,

U.

[1](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/dummys-guide-writing-web-service-clients-wso2-wsf-c#Running_Your_First_Web_Service_Client_with_WSO2_WSF_CPP)[http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/dummys-guide-writing-web-service-clients-wso2-wsf-c#Running_Your_First_Web_Service_Client_with_WSO2_WSF_CPP]

Answer (score 0):

Set the environemnt variable WSFCPP_HOME to your WSO2 CPP installation path.
Seems your path is not set correctly thats why you are seeing this error.
(I can run the samples in linux)